# Is there a universal definition of free software?

Tags: free-software-definition

I was reading the question

[Are discriminatory free licenses still free?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/are-discriminatory-free-licenses-still-free)

Regardless the merit of that particular question, one answers states that according to the definition

> The license must not discriminate against any person or group of persons.

However, I was under the impression that there is still some debate about what does or does not constitute a free software licence? A short note can be found on the [related Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_license#Controversial_borderline_cases), but one can see that a few different bodies categorizes the different licenses: OSI, FSF, Debian, etc.

So using licences that are already available make it clear if you fall in one or another definition. However with custom-made licences, it does not seem too clear to me.

Can someone clarify that for me, or is there a universally accepted definition of "free software licence"?

---

**Edit** It came in the comments, as well as a VTC. So I should adress it in the question. I have read the question

[What is the difference between free as in beer and free as in speech?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/620/what-is-the-difference-between-free-as-in-beer-and-free-as-in-speech)

and corresponding answers. I understand perfectly well the difference between *free* as in beer vs in speech. Let us forget about beers for the time being. Now, that question does not adress what I am asking here. There are different "free" licenses, most give some restriction. There are several bodies defining which licenses are free (I know of OSI, FSF and Debian, for example). They do not seem in effect, to agree on the freedom of certain licenses. So is there a more restricted, somewhat universal definition of a free software?

<sub>Note that I originally asked that question on [meta](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-does-free-mean-in-free-software), but was suggested to ask it here.</sub>

Comment: either free speech or free beer: see http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/620/64

Comment: @ratchetfreak yes, you made that same comment on meta, but it is only answering the title of my question, not the rest, isn't it? I am asking what constitutes "free" in "free speech".

Comment: which is answered in the second paragraph of the [accepted answer](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/621/64)

Comment: @ratchetfreak No it doesn't. For example, it does not include the quotation that I have in my question.

Comment: ["The freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose (freedom 0)."](https://gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) forbids discrimination of usage or users. That said, people either accept the [Free Software Definition](https://gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) or they don't. There is no universal acceptance.

Comment: @EricGärtner it forbids discrimination of usage, not access to the source and/or relicensing, which, I assume what the aim of the said question.

Comment: Well, what is *your* question?

Comment: @EricGärtner, well you actually provide an answer it in your previous comment: *"either accept the Free Software Definition or they don't. There is no universal acceptance."* This was my feeling/understanding but I wasn't sure of that.

Comment: For the dupe voters: I'm not entirely sure how the candidate post is a dupe: This one asks for a definition of the license, while the other asks for interpretation of the word "free"

Comment: free stands for freedom and it is called free software because user is "free". Also [translations](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/fs-translations.html) may help.

Comment: @Pandya, please see the edit.

Comment: How universal is universal? Who's opinion shall count?

Comment: may [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free) help

Comment: I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) as Universal definition of "Free Software"

Answer (score 10):

> However, I was under the impression that there is still some debates about what does or does not constitutes a free software licence?

I don't think there are still any *serious* debates about this.

However, assuming this question is an earnest one, there are *two* recognized definitions of of Free Software:

1. The [Free Software Definition](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) by the FSF, where the *four essential freedoms* are defined (making it clear that it is a matter of "freedom", not price).
2. The [Open Source Defintion](http://opensource.org/osd) of the OSI, which starts out by stating that "Free Redistribution" means the freedom to give away or to sell, *without restrictions*.

While there are subtle differences between the two, as answered in:
[What are the philosophical differences between open source and free/libre software (if they exist at all)?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/846/what-are-the-philosophical-differences-between-open-source-and-free-libre-softwa) - they boil down to the same definition of "free" - that the idea is to provide maximum *freedom* for users and developers, *except* the freedom to constrain others. In *practical* terms (but not in political) these two definitions of "free" are equivalent.

> However with custom-made licences, it does not seem too clear to me.

"Custom-made licenses" should be avoided.  IMHO, they are a huge problem for the FLOSS community, as they often make it impossible to combine works because of trivial license incompatibilities. Also they are often written by people ignorant about copyright law, making them a legal hazard to use.

Comment: This is a good answer. To expand on the bit about custom licenses, basically, custom-made licenses (even if they are simple modifications to well-known licenses) frequently fail to qualify as "free/open" under either the FSF or OSI definition, and fail to be GPL-compatible. In most cases this will be because they have a restriction about *how the software may be used*. For example, taking a free license like BSD modified and adding a clause like "must be used for good" or "non-commercial use only". Even though well-meaning, these are still restrictions that will disqualify it as free/open.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a universal definition of free software?

I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) is universally accepted definition of "Free Software"
(Also visit [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition)).

> - Freedom 0: The freedom to run the program for any purpose.
> - Freedom 1: The freedom to study how the program works, and change it to make it do what you wish.
> - Freedom 2: The freedom to redistribute copies so you can help your neighbor.
> - Freedom 3: The freedom to improve the program, and release your improvements (and modified versions in general) to the public, so that the whole community benefits.

And

> ...is there a universally accepted definition of "free software licence"?

I think [Free software license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_license) is universal.

Universally Accepted Free Software Licenses are:

- [FSF Approved Licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_license#FSF-approved_.22free_software.22_licenses) : [This](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html)
- [OSI Approved Linceses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_license#OSI-approved_.22open_source.22_licenses) : [This](http://opensource.org/licenses)